# Check unique Username in dotnetNuke validations

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

i have following code in which i want to validate that if entered username is already exists or not.
I checked inbuilt validation of dotNetNuke but i didn't understand anything.
 following is inbuilt code..

```
UserInfo user = UserController.GetUserByName(PortalId, User.Username);
if (user != null)
{
    if (PortalSettings.Registration.UseEmailAsUserName)
    {
        CreateStatus = UserCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail;
    }
    else
    {
        CreateStatus = UserCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName;
        int i = 1;
        string userName = null;
        while (user != null)
        {
            userName = User.Username + "0" + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            user = UserController.GetUserByName(PortalId, userName);
            i++;
        }
        User.Username = userName;
    }
}
```

and my code is as following.

```
public HttpResponseMessage SaveClientDetail(ClientDto dto)
{
    var user = new UserInfo();
    UserCreateStatus CreateStatus;
    user.FirstName = dto.FirstName;
    user.LastName = dto.LastName;
    user.Email = dto.Email;
    user.Username = dto.Email;
    user.DisplayName = dto.FirstName + " " + dto.LastName;


    UserController.CreateUser(ref user);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dto);
}
```

i want to validate my **user.Username** before the creation of object.
and also please give explanation about Inbuilt code that makes me understand this
Reply fast..

Answer (score 0):

The code basically gets a UserInfo object based on "username", if that Object is NULL, you can assume that the username doesn't exist.

Comment: if i write this following code                                                                  **UserInfo user = UserController.GetUserByName(PortalId, User.Username);** than every time user is coming null whether is unique or not.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, there is not any DNN method to validate single Username. You have to pass UserData object like below, that will give you status of your object like `DuplicateUserName`, `DuplicateDisplayName`, `DuplicateEmail`...etc

```
DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserCreateStatus objCreateStatus =
DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.CreateUser(ref objUser);
```

If you want to check duplicate Username before pass your UserData object to `CreateUser` method, I suggest you to create single method in your class that will return bool value true/false. You can write query like below and get Count number of existing Usernames. If query return any `Count > 0` then method return true otherwise false.

**Sample Method:**

```
public bool validateUsername(string fsUsername)
{
     bool lbFlag = false;
     int liCount = 0;
     // query = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE [Username] = '@Username'

     // Write C# code to get you count value

     if(liCount > 0)
     {
         lbFlag = true;
     }

     return lbFlag;
}
```

After call this method before you create UserData object. If you need more information about User Creation in DNN, I request you to [read this link](http://usersimporter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#UsersImporter.ascx.cs) at-least once.

Please let me know if you have any questions.